# UMVUE for $g(p) = \mathbb{E}_p[X^2]$, where X follows a geometric distribution

Tags: self-study, estimation, unbiased-estimator, exponential-family, umvue

I have a random variable X with pmf

$$p_\lambda(x) = (1-p)^{x-1}p, \ \ x = 1,2,3,\ldots, \ \ p \in (0,1)$$

and I am trying to find a UMVUE for $$g(p) = \mathbb{E}_p[X^2]$$.

Here is my attempt so far:

$$g(p) = \mathbb{E}_p[X^2] = \frac{2-p}{p^2}$$ and therefore, an unbiased estiator for $g(p)$ is $X^2$.

Furthermore, since the geometric distribution belongs to the exponential family of distributions, $$T(X) = \sum_i X_i$$ is a complete and sufficient statistic. Therefore, using the Lehman-Scheffé theorem, $$\mathbb{E}[X^2 |\sum_i X_i]$$ is a UMVUE for $g(p)$.

I can't seem to move forward from this point, in order to evaluate the expectation. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the sum over? Do you have multiple realizations, or just a sample of size 1?

Comment: @Greenparker Just a sample of size 1

Comment: Then the sufficient statistic is not $\sum_i X_i$, but rather simply $X$.

Comment: @Greenparker Yes, you're right ! And therefore, I have $\mathbb{E}[X^2|X] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] = \frac{2-p}{p^2}$, am I right?

Comment: Almost. You have $E[X^2 | X] = X^2$, which is your UMVUE (since UMVUE has to be the actual estimator, and not it's expectation).